# jQuery: hide and show

Tags: jquery

I have a "link" you press, textfield comes up(`toggle()`) with a submit button. When you submit it, on success on my ajax I have:

```
$('#RespondMsg' + id).hide();
$("#response" + id).fadeOut('slow');
```

Now the "link" remains, if you want to do it again. But since I have this, `hide()` and `fadeOut()`, the fields wont appear again, how can I solve this?

I tried with a timeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#RespondMsg' + id).show();
}, 1000);
```

But yeah that just shows the field again after 1 second.

So I want it to hide on success, and then if you press on the "link", it should show the fields again (#respondmsg, #response)

This is my "link" how it looks like:

```
$('.reply').live('click', function () {
    $('#replyWall'+$(this).attr('data-id')).toggle();
    document.getElementById('replyMsg'+$(this).attr('data-id')).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.reply').live('click', function () {
       var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
       $('#replyWall'+id).toggle();
       $('#RespondMsg' + id).hide();
       $("#response" + id).show();
       $('replyMsg'+id).focus();
});
```

Comment: How so?  Javascript error?  Not showing the element you want it to show?

Comment: Now when i press on the .reply the elements doesnt show (RespondMsg)